# Sharepoint 2007 and SQL 2005 Licensing

Tags: 2007, licensing

My company needs to setup a server for MOSS Standard 2007 and SQL Server Standard 2007.
I find the questions regarding CALs confusing, as there are conflicting documentation regarding it, so here I am.

There will be 4 employees working on development team for SharePoint projects, so my question is:

As it is for development, do I need 5 standard CALs for MOSS and 5 standard CALs for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to give precise answer to your question without exact details on your existing licensing contract with Microsoft, company size etc. It is always best to talk to Microsoft in your country/region or with a Microsoft reseller.

In a typical scenario you DO need both SharePoint and SQL server CALs for each user. In case you have a SQL Server processor license SQL CALs are included.

Since you will be using these for development I would suggest you take look at [MSDN subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa718661.aspx) which could be ideal for a development team, as you will get a lot of Microsoft products (Visual Studio, Office, Servers...) for a small price.

In case you are developing something on top of Microsoft technologies you can also check [Microsoft Partner Program](http://partner.microsoft.com) and [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/).

Comment: I've checked this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx and the version that includes SharePoint is the "Visual Studio Premium with MSDN". But the indicated price is per USER?

Also, does it allows downgrades? (as 2010 is the current version MS is selling, and I need 2007)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes MSDN is priced per user, but each subscription allows licensed user to run all MS applications listed. MSDN includes all version of Microsoft products e.g. you can run SharePoint 2003, 2007 and 2010. But talk with someone from Microsoft in your country before placing an order.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, you can get a SQL Server developer license (which includes the server license and a CAL) for about $35 per developer (i.e., dirt cheap).  The SQL Server developer edition includes all features that appear in the enterprise version.

And as Toni mentioned yes, in addition to SQL licenses, you will also need the MOSS standard CAL for each developer and a MOSS server license for each server that you stand up.